# Uploading images to a different domain using php

Tags: php, image, cross-domain, image-uploading

I am working on an application which allows user to create his own HTML templates and publish them to internet.The user can upload and use images for the purpose.

**Problem Statement:**
The user has to create a **domain** before he publishes his template.I use **cpanel** functions to create the domain.But,I also want to upload his images to his created domain and use the same images(i.e their location) when the user comes back to edit the template.I don't want separate copies on both the domains!The user edits his website on **www.xyz.com** and he creates and publishes it at **ABC.xyz.com**(can be a subdomain or main domain).So,I want the images to be uploaded at ABC.xyz.com and the same path to be reflected on the edit domain,so the overhead of storing multiple images is avoided.Will this involve **cross domain** scripting?(I believe yes!)
I am not able to start due to incomplete understanding of how this can be achieved!I would like to know how I can proceed with it?Any help would be good for me to start in the right direction.
**Note**: Will be updating the code if I get started.

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't require cross domain scripting.
You wont need to upload the files directly from the browser to another domain.

You can just upload em to your server and from there copy (if it's on the same server)  or ftp/scp/whatever you do to upload em.

The tricky part might be to allow user to do the changes on his website.  but i believe you are doing it as same server...  so a simple use of apache mod_alias will get it right.

Comment: The server can be different at times as user may opt for their own domain server.Now,if I can do FTP dynamically via code,I am not sure!Also,I have to move my **html** files from my local domain to users when he publishes it for first time,but that should be doable I believe images seem to be a problem for uploading as I want to have a single copy accessed at both domains

Comment: Do that pose any security issues??Is it safe enough to make ftp via code.Also,the user would be switching back forth from publish to edit!For reference,this is somewhat similar [here](http://app.imcreator.com)

Comment: in order to ftp the files for the user server you will need his password. so yes, it poses a security risk for the user using your service.

Comment: If you have a look at the link I menationed it has implemented something similar.Can you please throw some light on how it is handled over there as I am working on the similar grounds?It would be of great help.Thank you

Comment: Thank you for that but I am looking at how the images must be handled.Thank you for the help.I will work on your suggested lines and try to get it working!

Comment: I had a thought about a different approach.Having a upload script attached to each domain(i.e a upload.php).Whenever,the user tries to upload an image,I give a call to the function in the upload file and execute it.The image would be uploaded directly to the domain of the user.When the user comes back to re-edit his site,the images would be fetched from his domain.So,we have a single copy being used at both points.In this scenario,I am not sure how I can call the script   on the users domain from my domain?Can you help me with this?This would avoid the use of user password and be efficient!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what your setup is, but I would use a virtual host for the sub-domains and point them to a folder that resides inside of the xyz.com domain.

So for example, a user edits his website on xyz.com and xyz.com stores those images to xyz.com/ABC/images. Then, the subdomain ABC.xyz.com actually points to the xyz.com/ABC folder as it's root www directory.

If you for whatever reason have the domains hosted on two separate computers, you could use an ftp or cp script on a cron job to keep the files on the other system mirrored to the ones on the xyz.com domain.

Here is an example of an ftp uploading a local file to an external server:

```
public function ExecFTPUpload($local_file, $uploadfilename){
    $handle = fopen($local_file, 'r');

    $success = true;

    $conn_id = ftp_connect($this->config->ftpserver);

    // check connection 
    if ($conn_id && ($login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $this->config->ftp_user_name, $this->config->ftp_user_pass))) {
         ftp_pasv($conn_id, true); 
        // try to upload $local_file and save it to $handle
        if(!ftp_fput($conn_id, $uploadfilename, $handle, FTP_ASCII)) $success = false;
        ftp_close($conn_id);  
    }else $success = false;

    return $success;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the inputs.The pointing mechanism is what we use it currently and we want to rid of it as some users want it to be hosted on their own domains(which are totally different) and then we have again run commands and do the pointing part.Hence,we want to automate it,and keep the images on the users domain from the out set.

Comment: I see a couple of options for you then:

Have them setup an image upload script that you can POST form data to.

OR

Have the user upload the file to your server, instantly ftp or scp it to the clients server and update the address to that image.

Comment: Well the user does not have access to write any script.Do you mean I have a php file or upload script on the users domain(say **ABC.xyz.com**) and send a request to upload(call a function there from my domain i.e **\www.xyz.com**) the image on that domain?If I get you right can you help me how can I start with this?

Comment: Updated answer with an FTP upload function I wrote awhile back. That should give you a good start on how to send files over to the other server.

Comment: Thank you.A few doubts:-So this file would reside on my domain itself??I won't need it on the users domains?Is it secure enough?Also,when I want them on the edit domain,will the `img src="http://ABC.xyz.com"` work on my domain?

Comment: A couple of things, first you would want to use a relative link to the image. If you were on ABC.xyz.com/index.php and your image was at ABC.xyz.com/images/foo.png you would put: <img src="images/foo.png" /> into the page. Second, I would recommend making a cronjob that keeps all of the files on the clients server the same as the files on your server. So you manage the files into your system and then a cron job fires that automatically updates the clients server to the correct files. Since the domain for the clients would point to their system, nobody would ever access the files on your system

Comment: Well no experience or knowledge of **cron jobs**. :P Will check it out if that would solve the problem!Thank you!

Comment: I will need a Cron job to fire when the user publishes his copy,bcoz only then the page content would be updated on the server.If he just saves it,it will be saved in the database as draft copies and used for the user to **preview** his pages before publish!

Comment: I had a thought about a different approach.Having a upload script attached to each domain(i.e a upload.php).Whenever,the user tries to upload an image,I give a call to the function in the upload file and execute it.The image would be uploaded directly to the domain of the user.When the user comes back to re-edit his site,the images would be fetched from his domain.So,we have a single copy being used at both points.In this scenario,I am not sure how I can call the script   on the users domain from my domain?Can you help me with this?This would avoid the use of user password and be efficient!

Comment: That plan will work. The form for image uploading on your server would just point to the upload script on the clients server. <form method="POST" action="abc.xyz.com/upload.php?returnlocation=xyz.com/mypage.php'></form> What you can do is have that page redirect back to your site using the location specified in the the returnlocation request variable.

Comment: I believe I can use some kind of **ajax uploader** as I cannot refresh the page.The image has to be uploaded asynchronously.So,there should not be any problem for me to upload image to different domain(**Any security or permission issue-->If you can point me to that**).Thank you for your response till now